# Subset data frame using object of type character

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame called `worksheet2`.

```
print(head(worksheet2))
         v3        v4        v5
1 -38.37020 -103.6463 -2.116447
2 -37.51055 -109.0798 -2.250305
3 -37.95210 -107.4237 -2.196817
4 -38.57173 -109.1353 -2.318979
5 -38.69677 -109.7195 -2.239646
6 -38.32972 -110.4375 -2.115808
```

where

```
ncol(worksheet2)
130
```

I am running a function that returns an object `vif` of type character with column names that are not collinear.

```
print(vif)
[1] "v10"  "v13"  "v15"  "v19"  "v22"  "v23"  "v25"  "v29"  "v32"  "v34"  "v36"  "v38" "v40"  "v44"  "v46"  "v48"  "v49"
```

I would like to subset `worksheet2` so that only the columns from `vif` remain.

I've tried searching for answers to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `worksheet2[vif]`?

Comment: `subset(worksheet2, select=vif)`

Comment: `worksheet2[,vif]` if you're not into the whole brevity thing

Comment: @JakeBurkhead You know, those commas will give you carpal tunnel.  And where is the space after the comma! ;)

Comment: @BrodieG thank you, I was totally over-thinking it.